# Else statement always runs after if and if else

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
//run...
printf("----------------CALC--------------\n");
printf("(1) Type in a letter to get a secret message: ");
int validSecret = 0;
char secretLetter;
while(validSecret == 0){
    scanf("%c",&secretLetter);
    if(secretLetter == 'b'){
        printf("B\n");
    }
    else if (secretLetter == 'r'){
        printf("R\n");
    }
    else if (secretLetter == 'k'){
        printf("K\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Game over\n");
        validSecret = 1;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

If I enter `a` `b` the if statement executes correctly and prints a B and a new line but also prints game over. It's running the if and the else... This makes no sense.

Comment: The culprit is `scanf("%c",&secretLetter);`. Use `scanf(" %c",&secretLetter);`

Comment: Print out the `char` it read.

Comment: wondering how many Qs have already been raised about this `scanf("%c"..)` issue

Comment: @artm: probably about as many as `fflush(stdout)`, but less than `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: I already earned 20 rep answering this kind of Q - so now whenever I saw `scanf("%c"..` I know that it's where the problem is, no matter how the question (something something doesn't work) may sound different :))

Answer (score 1):

The newline you've entered (corresponding to a `'\n'` character) doesn't match any of the other conditions; of course your code will take the `else` branch because of it.

Is it possible that `stdin` could reach `EOF`? Your code ignores the return value, and so wouldn't be able to detect such scenarios... It should probably look more like:

```
while (scanf("%c", &secretLetter) == 1) {
    if (secretLetter == 'b') {
        printf("B\n");
    }
    else if (secretLetter == 'r'){
        printf("R\n");
    }
    else if (secretLetter == 'k'){
        printf("K\n");
    }
    else if (secretLetter != '\n') {
        printf("Game over\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Notice how I converted your `else` to an `else if (secretLetter != '\n')`? This should prevent "Game over" from being printed when `secretLetter` is `\n`, solving the first problem...

Also notice how I made the terminal condition of the loop match the failure of `scanf`? This should prevent the loop from continuing when `stdin` reaches `EOF`. You might want to move the `printf("Game over\n");` to outside of the loop to account for this.

You don't need an intermediate variable in place of `break` here; you should avoid unnecessary clutter at all cost.

Answer (score 0):

After you read input, you need to flush the input buffer, like so

```
void flush()
{
    while (getchar() != '\n')
        ;
}
```

This is so that all characters up to, and including, the newline are consumed. The reason is that `scanf` stops reading as soon as it sees the `'\n'`, so it leaves it in the inpu buffer. Also, never flush wih `fflush(stdin)`, because that isn't portable.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `'\n'` input by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> is also consumed by `scanf()`. You can use

```
scanf(" %c", &secretLetter);
```

to discard these whitespaces (including `' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n'` and something else).